# Global variables vs. parameters for read-only access

Tags: python, multithreading, global

I'm wondering what the difference is between this code:

```
import multiprocessing 

g = {} # global data dictionary

class Foo:
   @staticmethod
   def bar():
      elems = [1,2,3,4,5]
      g["important_data"] = get_important_data()
      with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as p:
         for res in p.imap(f, elems):
            # do whatever
```

where `f` is a function that will use `g["important_data"]` in a read-only manner; and this code:

```
import multiprocessing

class Foo:
   @staticmethod
   def bar():
      elems = [1,2,3,4,5]
      important_data = get_important_data()
      with multiprocessing.Pool(10) as p:
         for res in p.imap(f, (elems, important_data)):
            # do whatever
```

where `f` does exactly the same computation on `elems` as above, but is handed the additional data as a parameter `important_data`, rather than acessing it via the global variable `g`.

I'm currently working with code where the original authors wrote the comment `# Globals for multiprocessing to prevent shared memory` over `g`, but I don't know what this means. I know that different processes in python have their own copies of global variables by default (so the first implementation would no work at all if `f` were meant to write in `g`; however, as mentioned, this is read-only), but the second implementation seems to copy `important_data` as well, so where's the difference?

Comment: There's not much we can tell you without a *complete* [mcve]. In a similar situation, one might want to avoid using *instance* "variables" (aka attributes) to avoid having them copied along with the instance – but your code has no instance, and ``bar`` cannot even receive ``self``.

Comment: `bar` is actually static. Other than that, I don't know how I'm supposed to give you more details. `f` does stuff. It's very complicated stuff. I don't know what aspects about the operation change the answer to the question, so I don't know what aspects to include. I can guarantee that you don't want me to include everything.

Comment: I think anything that isn't just a meaningless stub might help. Perhaps you can describe the missing pieces? Why is there even a ``Foo``? What kind of data is provided by ``get_important_data()``? What quality of code are we talking about here – did the original authors even know what they were doing most of the time? How *does* ``f`` access ``g`` in the original code anyway?

Comment: #1: This sort of pattern is OS specific, as it requires "fork" rather than "spawn". Otherwise, `g` will exist, but `g["important_data"] = get_important_data()` won't be called in the child leaving it empty. #2 explicitly passes the data as an argument which is more expensive, but also more portable.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to read about fork and spawn and I think I get the difference and why forking is needed here. I am running Linux, and I'd be shocked if the original authors didn't, so this would be why it works. What I don't understand is why #2 is more expensive. To implement a fork, surely the current state, which includes `g["important_data"]`, has to be copied. So why is this copy-by-fork less expensive than copying it explicitly by passing it as an argument?

Comment: Under "fork" the new process gets access to the memory pages of the old process via "copy on write" so all static data is copied "for free" (including the executable). "Spawn" starts a new process sharing no data at all from the parent, and all necessary data gets `import`ed from the `__main__` file. In both cases the function to be executed and the arguments are then `pickle`d and sent to the child process via a pipe. This process is comparatively expensive, so sending large amounts of data via the arguments can be slow.

Comment: Thank you -- I think you've pretty answered my question (I would mark your comment if it weren't a comment). Note that the code does ML stuff and both performance and memory are very much bottlenecks, so it makes a lot of sense for the authors to make use of tricks like this one.